# Offline message to show that the application is offline

Tags: android, offline

Guys I am developing a app online and I would like to know, how I can put a code in my app, for to display a message that it is offline, style the same of the message that is seen in app of the Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function to check if you are online:

```
 private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

Your manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```